# How can one write a WatchOS widget for accessoryCorner family that renders appropriately?

Tags: watchos

I'm trying to build a widget that has a gauge like in the image attached. It does not seem like there are any APIs to render the gauge (or any other view for that matter) on an arc, depending on which corner is used.

[image: Screenshoot]

Is there any such support, or are such widgets only available to Apple? E.g. can one tell which corner the widget is being rendered in, so that the correct transformations be computed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get close to an Apple style corner widget, but there are currently some limitations. As far as I know you have to use the [.widgetLabel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/widgetLabel(label:)) modifier which restricts you to an "Image, Text, Gauge, ProgressView, or a container with multiple subviews".

The styling for the Gauge and ProgressView seem to be predefined as well - for example styling the gauge with `.gaugeStyle(LinearCapacityGaugeStyle())` doesn't change the appearance.

```swift
var body: some View {
      switch widgetFamily {
      case .accessoryCorner: // WatchOS only
         Text("50%") // Watch out for clipping
            .font(.system(size: 20))
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .widgetLabel {
               ProgressView(value: 0.5)
                  .tint(.blue)
            }
      }
}
```

or

```swift
var body: some View {
      switch widgetFamily {
      case .accessoryCorner: // WatchOS only
         Text("50%") // Watch out for clipping
            .font(.system(size: 20))
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .widgetLabel {
               Gauge(value: 50.0, in: 0...100) {
                  Text("Not shown")
               } currentValueLabel: {
                  Text("Not shown")
               } minimumValueLabel: {
                  Text("0") // Watch out for clipping
               } maximumValueLabel: {
                  Text("100") // Watch out for clipping
               }
               .tint(.blue)
               .gaugeStyle(LinearCapacityGaugeStyle()) // Doesn't do anything
            }
```

Gives you:

[image]
[image]

You can rotate the text manually to try and make it line up with corner, but as you say then there doesn't seem to be a way to identify which corner the widget is in so you don't know which way to rotate it...

Comment: Good answer. Just one thing: your code comment says "watch out for clipping", but you could just use .minimumScaleFactor(0.6) on the Text view. Choose whatever scale factor you think is appropriate and the text will shrink rather than clip.

Comment: Yes that should work! But I think in this case (and hopefully its fixed now) I vaguely remember I ended up setting a fixed font because otherwise it made the text too small or too big and it clipped anyway or something dumb like that :)

Answer (score 5):

[Apple forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707827) has a solution!

.widgetCurvesContent()

```
var body: some View {
    Text("Hi")
        .widgetCurvesContent()
        .widgetLabel("World!")
}
```

Comment: This requires watchOS 10+

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug introduced in `watchOS 9.0` when they migrated `Complications` to `WidgetKit`, and still present as of `watchOS 9.4`. It has been an irritating issue that Apple refuses to acknowledge even though the curved design was present before; they downgraded it to mediocrity without warning.

Please contribute and complain on the [Apple forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707827) and also post Apple feedback. It was a big downgrade to the Complications with no warning and also misrepresented in the [Human Interface Guideline](https://%20https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/system-experiences/complications/#corner.).